# Relationship between the autocorrelation functions of a random variable and a transformation (log) of the same variable

Tags: time-series, data-transformation, autocorrelation, logarithm

Are there any general results for the relationship between the autocorrelation function (acf) of a random variable and the acf of a transformation of the same variable?

I am particularly interested in the relationship between the acf of realized variance and the logarithm of realized variance.